# NextJs app router with redux-toolkit for SSR not setting to initial state after navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, redux, redux-toolkit

I have a simple project using NextJs with the `app` router, and I am also using `redux/redux-toolkit` for state management, but I am having some small issues.

When I populate the redux state on "page1", and the user navigates to "page2", the data that has been fetched on "page1" still exists on the redux state even though I did not fetch those data on the "page2". The same thing when the user goes back to "page1" from "page2", the data that I fetch on the "page2" still exists in the redux state.

To give you an idea of what I mean, I created this simple CodeSandbox where you can check.
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/nextjs-redux-toolkit-z5x2tw

I am using the `<a>` tag for navigations because the idea is to fetch the data every time the user navigates to a different page. When the user navigates to "Pokemons", we populate the `pokemons` state, and when the user navigates to "Pokemon" (without 's'), we only fetch and populate the `pokemon` (without 's') state.

We are expecting that the redux state should return to the initial state every time the user navigates to a different page since we don't use a persistent state library or save the state to any storage. I believe this should be the default behavior of redux/redux-toolkit, or am I missing something?

Comment: Why *would* it do that? What makes you think that would be the expected default behavior? You don't have any actions to clear out any state values when navigating around the app. Also, why would you want to do this in the first place, you'll just have to refetch data again when navigating back to the first page, creating a lot of extra unnecessary network traffic? Your React components also don't appear to be correctly subscribed to the provided Redux store, they should use the `useSelector` hook instead of getting the current state as an unintentional side-effect.

Comment: Hi Drew, well consider this scenario, especially on e-commerce. When the user is on the Product-List-Page (PLP) and clicks on a product, it goes to a different page, Product-Details-Page (PDP), it fetches the product data and shows it to the page. When the user returns to PLP, do you need to keep the product data from PDP? Also, the page is not SPA, so we are using an anchor tag `<a>` instead of "next/link", this should be like navigating, requesting every time the user navigates.

Comment: From the code it looks to me like you are trying to use `redux` to manage state on the `server side`. And from your question it looks like you are expecting the server to reset it's state on page load. But the thing is that, even if you are on serverless, the server state will persist between requests, even for different clients. So it is on you to reset the server's store at the start (or end) of every request. But I feel like the fact that you are using `redux` on `server side` is an accident.

Comment: Hi @zoran404, thank you for your response and yes, we are using `redux` to manage our states. So our idea is something like this. When the page loads on the server, we fetch the data and save it to a `redux` state, this is because some components will also grab data from it, also for SSR (SEO especially). When the user navigates to a different page, we expect the redux to be in the initial state again, and we update the states while in the server once again.

Comment: I think I get what you want, but I don't think `redux` is the right tool here. `redux` would make more sense if you tried to persist data across all page loads. If I was you I'd write custom logic to sharing loaded data. There are probably libs specially for this, but I haven't used them myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that the NextJs state is persistent on every user navigation. If you are using `createContext`, `useContext` hooks, this can be solved by `import { unstable_noStore } from 'next/cache';` [documentation here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/unstable_noStore), though, this doesn't work with Redux. Even using `templates.(js/tsx)` [documentation here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/template), the store still becomes persistent.

To solve this, I add a `revertAll` action on every slice then call it on every page to reset the store on every navigation. I am not sure if this is the correct approach but this solves my concern. Sample code below:

```
redux/slice/global.ts

export const global = createSlice({
  name: "global",
  initialState,
  extraReducers(builder: any) {
    builder.addCase(revertAll, () => initialState);
    ...
  },
  reducers: {
    ...
  },
});
```

Then calling this function to revert the store every time the user navigates

```
app/page.tsx

async function getData() {
  reduxStore.dispatch(revertAll());
  ...
}

export default async function Page() {
  await getData();
  ...
  }
```

I hope this helps someone having the same concern. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are maintaining the Redux state server-side, so anything the client does is a bit irrelevant, Single-Page App or not. If you would like the `pokemons` state to reset to `[]` when navigating to the details page, and for the `pokemon` state to reset to `{}` when navigating to the home page, these are state changes you need to manage yourself, manually, when these specific actions are dispatched and handled in the reducers.

Example:

```js
const initialState: IGlobal = {
  name: "pokeapi.co",
  versionHash:
    versionHashEnv.length > 5 ? versionHashEnv.substring(0, 5) : versionHashEnv,
  loading: false,
  pokemon: {},
  pokemons: [],
};

export const global = createSlice({
  name: "global",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setLoading: (state, action: PayloadAction<boolean>) => {
      state.loading = action.payload;
    },
    setPokemon: (state, action: PayloadAction<IPokemon | {}>) => {
      state.pokemon = action.payload;
      state.pokemons = []; // <-- reset when setting pokemon data
    },
    setPokemons: (state, action: PayloadAction<IPokemons | []>) => {
      state.pokemons = action.payload;
      state.pokemon = {}; // <-- reset when setting pokemons array data
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Drew, this is also what I am thinking but I want to get advice from others like you. I'm just wondering why `redux` is not going back to the **initial** state when the user navigates to a different page, because it's like every time the user navigates, it's like a new visit to the page so I was thinking it should start from the **initial** state, or am I missing something here? Thank you.